# any mature library in Haskell for network packets handling?

Tags: haskell, network-programming, scapy

any mature library in Haskell for network packets handling?

in python we have scapy, any similar thing in Haskell world?

thank you!

Comment: Library recommendations are off topic on Stack Overflow. However, there's a change that a tightly-specified, criterion-based question could be on topic on the [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange site](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the [pcap](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pcap) library for system-independent packet capture.